# my expandable list view contain a listView

Tags: android, focus, expandablelistview, onitemclicklistener

my expandable list view contains a childLayout with a listView. but my on item click listener for this listView is didn't worked....

how i get this onItemClickListener for the listView.

Answer (score 1):

It's completely normally - ItemClick event handled by top level ExpandableListView and this event don't deliever to child ListView. You can deliever ItemClick event to ListView if you `return false` in `onItemClick` method which handles item click on ExpandableListView.
I think the best approach will be change your layout stucture - it's not good idea to put ListView into ExpandableListView and handle events like this will bring too many headache to you.